# Unit-testing expect script

Tags: testing, tcl, expect

I have an expect script that I would like to do unit-tests for, but I'm unsure how to go about it.

My initial thought was to override `keychain`, `lpass` and `bw` somehow, but I have no idea how to do this without modifying the original script, in my other tests I have overridden functions with shell function stubs and set `PATH=''` in some cases. I guess I could test all the 3 executed commands manually, but that doesn't really test the project as a whole and leaves some code untested which is vital to the functionality.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --
set manager [lindex $argv 0]
# strip manager part
set argv [lrange $argv 1 end]
spawn -noecho keychain --quick --quiet --agents ssh {*}$argv
foreach key $argv {
  if {$manager == "lastpass"} {
    set pass [exec lpass show --name $key --field=Passphrase | tr -d '\n']
  }
  if {$manager == "bitwarden"} {
    set pass [exec bw get password $key | tr -d '\n']
  }
  expect ":"
  send "$pass\r"
}
interact
```

Any suggestions would be be highly appreciated!

Comment: i dont have `keychain` command so cannot try your code. could you provide a [repro]?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. The 2 commands literally output 'foo' password. keychain pre-authenticates ssh keys, so it will output and prompt `Passphrase:` for each keys in $argv. 

My best bet so far is making these commands into variables. This would enable me to test it easily.

Answer (score 1):

For *unit testing,* you can just put a directory at the start of the `PATH` with mock scripts for the `keychain`, `lpass` and `bw` commands. After all, in a unit test you're just really checking that the code *in the script itself* is plausible and doesn't contain stupid errors. Yes, there are other ways of doing that, but mocking the commands via a `PATH` tweak is definitely the easiest and most effective way.

*However,* this is definitely a case where the useful testing is *integration testing* where you run against the real commands. Of course, you might do that in some sort of testing environment; a VM (especially something comparatively lightweight like Docker) might help here.

You do not need to test whether `exec` and `spawn` obey the `PATH`. That's someone else's job and definitely is tested!